# Retrieving friends that also use App with Facebook SDK 5 for PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i'm using Facebook's SDK 5 for PHP.

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/friends?limit=5000', $access_token);
$friends = $response->getGraphEdge();
$extra = $friends->getMetaData();
```

I'm using this to get data about the user count, and also a list of friends that also use the app. This is the result:

```
Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphEdge Object
(
    [request:protected] => Facebook\FacebookRequest Object
        (
            [app:protected] => Facebook\FacebookApp Object
                (
                    [id:protected] => 1664093063314172
                    [secret:protected] => d7143261a3efv829060395e73288cc4b
                )

            [accessToken:protected] => EAAafYbjiAZAhwBAI4MLAxRgfEBa3qs9fhUmxz3L52xEsotBDwv2qNm4qgjhN5K1HVNGNEFoqJBlrfZAxyOGiW4PJkV51Jgp5OKfJAfJMZBSDWcyZAeZByic80MAFhNOFECWB8psanv4qz2xY0szc6lAgN21uXw4ezBOF0EN4xVZBGQVDZD
            [method:protected] => GET
            [endpoint:protected] => /me/friends
            [headers:protected] => Array
                (
                    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
                )

            [params:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [files:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [eTag:protected] => 
            [graphVersion:protected] => v2.8
        )

    [metaData:protected] => Array
        (
            [paging] => Array
                (
                    [cursors] => Array
                        (
                            [before] => QVFIUmxELVdpV0FzQWJjb3lBZA3IwTlpTV0RpMUVfUFdiNzFmSk1xZAllaN2RSNmhUMsEzNEhyc3lfY2RfSzhMNTZAqQl96Q1dLUUsySGhma2FOSTl6RWZASSFBR
                            [after] => QVFIUmxELVdpV0FzQWJjb3lUHA3IwTlpTV0RpMUVfUFdiNzFjSk1xZAllaN2RSNmhUMsEzNEhyc3lfY2RfSzhMNTZAqQl96Q1dLUUsySGhma2FOSTl6RWZASSFBR
                        )

                )

            [summary] => Array
                (
                    [total_count] => 5
                )

        )

    [parentEdgeEndpoint:protected] => 
    [subclassName:protected] => 
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode Object
                (
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => John Doe
                            [id] => 455583386691311
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

I need a way to grab the list of friends, in this case there is only one: John Doe (455583386691311). Which method can I use to convert that data into an array? Thanks!

Comment: isn´t there a "toArray" function in the php sdk?

Comment: @luschn can't seem to find anything related with a toArray() method in the reference documentation.

Comment: @luschn just found it, but the method it's actually called asArray(), thanks for the tip!